# Get TypeScript to export proper function name for closure-compiler?

Tags: javascript, typescript, minify, google-closure-compiler

I have the following TypeScript:

```
namespace CompanyName.HtmlTools.Cookie
{

    export function eraseCookie(name:string, path:string)
    {
        createCookie(name, "", path, -1);
    }


    export function readCookie(name:string) 
    {
        var nameEQ:string = name + "=";
        var ca:string[] = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) 
        {
            var c:string = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) 
                return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }


    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript
    // http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/
    export function createCookie(name:string, value:string, path:string, days:number) 
    {
        var expires:string = "";

        if(!path)
            path = "/";

        if (days) 
        {
            var date:Date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            expires = "expires=" + date.toUTCString() + "; ";
        }

        var allValues = name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + "; " + expires + "path=" + path + ";";
        if(window.location.protocol === 'https:')
            allValues += " secure;"

        document.cookie = allValues;
    }


    export function getDirName(path:string)
    {
        if(path === null) return '/';

        if(path.indexOf("/") !== -1)
        {
            var subs:string[] = path.split('/') //break the string into an array
            subs.pop() //remove its last element
            path = subs.join('/')  //join the array back into a string
            if(path === '')
                return '/';
            return path;
        }

        return "/";
    }


}
```

Now I want to be able to use a minimized & optimized JavaScript of this typescript like this:

```
CompanyName.HtmlTools.Cookie.createCookie("name","value", "path", 2);
```

However, when I run it through google closure-compiler (only in advanced mode), then the nice function names vanish, and I have CompanyName.HtmlTools.Cookie.f, which breaks all other scripts that use this script.

Now, the problem seems to be, that in the uncompressed javaScript that the TypeScript transpiler create, there is this:

```
Cookie.createCookie = createCookie;
```

if it was

```
Cookie["createCookie"] = createCookie;
```

then it would work in Closure-Compiler in advanced mode.

Is there any way to get TypeScript to export functions as

```
Cookie["createCookie"] = createCookie;
```

instead of

```
Cookie.createCookie = createCookie;
```

?

Same thing for the namespace, should be

```
})(window["CompanyName"]|| (window["CompanyName"] = {}));
```

instead of

> })(CompanyName || (CompanyName= {}));

Comment: I'm not an expert on Closure, but I would first look into fixing that option on Closure. I'm pretty surprised that its default behavior is to completely eliminate user-defined string maps just because it thinks they're only used internally.

Comment: @Katana314 That closure-compiler behavior is by design - but is only part of the Advanced mode of the compiler. It's definitely not a bug.

Comment: I'm curious, though; since a function's name is just as important as a module's name, what is stopping `CompanyName.HtmlTools.Cookie` from becoming `g.f.e`? It would still be possible to have all internal code work correctly against that if it's all part of the same compile process, but in the same vein it would break outside code.

Comment: @Katana314 Closure-compiler in advanced mode assumes that it is aware of all external libraries/code and all external uses of the source. If those assumptions are satisfied properly, `CompanyName.HtmlTools.Cookie` can become `var a`. http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html

Comment: @Katana314: Nothing, it is in fact g.f.e.; as I wrote below the question, "same thing for the namespace"

Answer (score 1):

Use a common superclass to store the static methods:

> In TypeScript, static properties of classes are inherited, in Closure they are not. To fix this, we create a common superclass.
>
> These fake superclasses don't actually exist and are present solely to simulate the behavior of `goog.inherits(SubClass, SuperClass)` in TypeScript definition files. Calling `new SuperClass__Class` or `extends SuperClass__Class` in non-declaration TypeScript code will generate a runtime error. You should use `new SuperClass` and `extends SuperClass` in non-declaration TypeScript code.

**References**

- [TypeScript Closure Tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-closure-tools)

Answer (score -1):

> Cookie["createCookie"] = createCookie;

Use this ^ workaround or switch of name mangling on closure compiler.

Comment: He's aware that works. He'd like to find a way to make TypeScript generate functions that way when compiling it into JavaScript.

Comment: @Katana314: Exactly; even if I do it by hand, Visual Studio will overwrite on the next change (which would be ok, if the generated code would work).

Comment: @basarat: That's the descripton of the problem, not the solution.